# Javascript or HTML - Select two items, show the sum

Tags: javascript, html, select, sum, items

**Found the answer! At the bottom of the page.**

I would like to select two items and produce the sum of both on a website.
**For instance**, let's say each number is a book :

> Row A = 1 (U$10), 2 (U$20), 3 (U$30), 4 (U$40).
>
> Row B = 5 (U$50), 6 (U$60), 7 (U$70), 8 (U$80).
>
> Row C = sum.

[Prototype](http://prntscr.com/6118ig)

It would only be possible to select 1 item per row. If I choose, for example, 1 and 7, I would like in Row C the value (U$) of the sum for both, so in this case 80.

Styling aside, is it possible to code that selection+sum?
Is there a way to do that that's not server-side, just client-side?

Comment: Sure, use `input type="radio"` or a `<select>`

Comment: It certainly possible, but we have to see your html to be able to help. Also, if you show your research, or what have you tried, people will more likely help you. (Please read this: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Basically would be something like this:
http://prntscr.com/6118ig
Most part of my research was to find if I could use an id selector (#choice1 and so forth), but it turned out not working. Google also didn't return anything I could use.

Will look into <select> and input type="radio", thanks.
Will keep that in mind @zord, thanks.

I don't want anyone coming here and chewing the answer, I just wanted someone to say: it's possible using <this method>. I would do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Paul S., I could find an answer through research.
 The youtubber Ralph Phillips (I love you, thank you) explains it very well.
He explains it with the usage of <select> and also forms (input type="radio").

Here are the links:

> [Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ze9ib99LvhY)
>
> [Final page](http://www.ralphphillips.com/youtube/stick-figure/stick-figure2.html)

It is a generic solution and someone with basic javascript/html skills can find the way around it and make it specific to attend his/her needs.